# Can Apache Ignite Continuous Queries miss some update?

Tags: datagrid, ignite

We are testing Apache Ignite Continuous Queries and during the tests, we have noticed that some continuous queries misses some updates of the cache.
Our use case is the following one:

- we have a feeder (that is part of the server nodes) and that feeds 1000 caches with data every seconds
- we have a client program (that is part of the server nodes) that opens 1000 continuous queries, 1 continuous query per cache

So, some of these continuous queries misses from times to times few updates of the cache. We were wondering whether the fact that a continuous query misses some updates of the cache was "normal".

We have also performed the test with 500, 250, 100 caches and have the same results.

Besides, we are also wondering how many caches and continuous queries can be created? Does Apache Ignite support hundred thousands of creation of caches and continuous queries?

Comment: Do you observe any exceptions?
Do you use a remote filter?

Comment: No exception is thrown. A remote filter has been used but it returned true during the tests.

Comment: How do you check that an update event is missing?  
Are there chances that several updates of the same entry end in the same batch?

Comment: Can this feeder issue concurrent updates to the same keys? What cache atomicity mode do you use (ATOMIC or TRANSACTIONAL)? If ATOMIC, what type of write ordering mode do you have (CLOCK or PRIMARY)?

Comment: @symbicator basically, the cache is fed with json objects. A new json objet is put in the cache with a key which is the insertion order. So, the key is 0, 1, 2, ... On the client side, we get these json objects and check whether we received all the objects by checking that no keys is missing.

Comment: @Alexey right now, we are using the default configuration of the examples (https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples). We've just add the size of the default cache to 1Mb. So, it seems that the default cache atomicity mode is ATOMIC. But I haven't found what is the default write ordering mode.

Comment: If you use the default configuration then write ordering should be PRIMARY.  
Which Ignite version do you use?

Comment: @symbicator we are using 1.0.9

Comment: @ctranxuan, just to clarify, 1.0.9 or 1.9.0 ?

Comment: @symbicator we are using 1.9.0. Sorry, mistyped... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer with the Ignite mailing-list (http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Can-a-Continuous-Queries-miss-some-updates-order-td11620.html#a11623):

> Continuous Query (CQ) garanties that the order for events will be preserved per entry. For example:

```
cache.put(key1, 100);
cache.put(key2, 100);
cache.put(key1, 200);
cache.put(key2, 200);
```

> CQ guarantees that for key1 events will be received in the following order (1, 100) --> (1, 200) but you can got event for key2 early than for key1. 
>   Ignite doesn't have limitation on count of caches and CQ.

Thanks Nikolai Tikhonov!

Answer (score 1):

Notifications should never be lost in continuous queries. If this actually happens, it's most likely a bug in the product or in your test. I would recommend to share your test with Apache Ignite community.

Comment: While cleaning the code to share it and adding more logs, it appears that the updates weren't not lost but some of them are not received in order they were put in the caches.
The source code of the tests can be found here: https://github.com/ctranxuan/ignite-cq-bench-parent
. There is a README.md